# OSX: Is it possible to mount RAID volume in any other OS except OSX?

Tags: mac-osx, software-raid

I've got 3 SATA hdds in my computer which is in fact - stripe software RAID volume. I want to transfer data from there. I know that Linux can read HFS+ file system. Is there's any chance to MOUNT whole RAID volume by it's ID somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although as you say there are a number of HFS+ filesystem drivers available I'm unaware of any that support HFS+ on a software RAID group other than OSX itself sorry.